# AsyncTask on doInBackground() String.length() null object reference

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, nullreferenceexception

maybe you can help me. My application allows you to save the a movieID from the API to a SQLiteDatabase. I am able to retrieve the movieID and userID successfully. When an API request is sent for the movie, the logs show that it is returned successfully as well but I keep getting the following error and the application restarts or crashes.

```
  05-19 18:43:10.118 8103-8103/? W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
05-19 18:43:15.263 2407-2626/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000 cmp=com.example.asc.app/.MovieList} from uid 10058 on display 0
05-19 18:43:15.283 8103-8103/? W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
05-19 18:43:15.293 8103-8103/? D/MovieList:: movie_user_id1
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/278?api_key=b5c3cfd30f424540a36db95684a067e0
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.example.asc.app.MovieHttpClient.getMovieData(MovieHttpClient.java:43)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.example.asc.app.MovieAsyncTask.doInBackground(MovieAsyncTask.java:21)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at com.example.asc.app.MovieAsyncTask.doInBackground(MovieAsyncTask.java:13)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-19 18:43:17.222 8103-8651/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8103/? W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8103/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8103/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8103/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:498)
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8103/? W/System.err:     at com.example.asc.app.MovieList.populateList(MovieList.java:106)
05-19 18:43:17.223 8103-8651/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                 Process: com.example.asc.app, PID: 8103
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                     at com.example.asc.app.JSONMovieParser.getMovie(JSONMovieParser.java:19)
                                                     at com.example.asc.app.MovieAsyncTask.doInBackground(MovieAsyncTask.java:26)
                                                     at com.example.asc.app.MovieAsyncTask.doInBackground(MovieAsyncTask.java:13)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

MovieList.java - where I want to display

```
public class MovieList extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

dbOpenHelper helper = new dbOpenHelper(this);
int movieID = -1;
int userID = 1;
String title = "MLTitle";
String posterPath = "MLPosterPath";
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_movielist);

    populateList();
}

public void populateList() {

    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    userID = ((ApplicationSession) getApplication()).getUserID();

    String[] projection = {
            helper.MOVIE_USER_ID,
            helper.MOVIE_REF_ID,
            helper.MOVIE_TITLE,
            helper.MOVIE_POSTER_PATH
    };

    String selection = helper.MOVIE_USER_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {Integer.toString(userID)};
    Log.d("MovieList: ", helper.MOVIE_USER_ID+userID); //Displays correct user id
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            helper.TABLE_MOVIES,                     // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
            null                                 // The sort order
    );

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            movieID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("movie_ref_id"));
            MovieAsyncTask task = new MovieAsyncTask();
            try {
                boolean search = false;
                String searchString = Integer.toString(movieID);
                JSONObject object  = task.execute(searchString, search).get();

                List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> posterpathList = new ArrayList<>();
                ListView movieList =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMovies);

                final int numberOfItemsInResp = object.length();
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInResp; i++)
                {
                    try{
                       title = object.get("title").toString();
                       posterPath = object.get("poster_path").toString();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //FILL LIST HERE
                    titlesList.add(title);
                    posterpathList.add(posterPath);
                }
                movieList.setAdapter( listAdapter );

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

MovieAsyncTask.java

```
public class MovieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

    String searchString = (String) params[0];
    boolean search = (boolean) params[1];

    String data = ( (new MovieHttpClient()).getMovieData(searchString, search));

    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    try {

        jObj = JSONMovieParser.getMovie(data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObj;
}
}
```

MovieHTTPClient.java

```
public class MovieHttpClient {

private static final String API_KEY = "?api_key=b5c3cfd30f424540a36db95684a067e0";
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
private static final String SEARCH = "search/movie";
private static final String MOVIE = "movie/";
private static final String QUERY = "&query=";

public String getMovieData(String searchString, boolean search) {

    HttpURLConnection con = null ;
    InputStream is = null;
    String url;

    try {
        if (search) {
            url = BASE_URL + SEARCH + API_KEY + QUERY;
            url += searchString;
        }else{
            url = BASE_URL + MOVIE + searchString + API_KEY;
        }
        con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        is = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(line + "\r\n");

        is.close();
        con.disconnect();

        return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { is.close(); } catch(Throwable t) {}
        try { con.disconnect(); } catch(Throwable t) {}
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Edit 1: btnSearch

```
 btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String searchString = txtSearch.getText().toString();
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            TextView tvRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRating);
            TextView tvReleaseDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReleaseDate);
            TextView tvOverview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOverview);
            ImageView imgVPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVPoster);
            boolean search = true;

            MovieAsyncTask task = new MovieAsyncTask();
            try {
                JSONObject object  = task.execute(searchString, search).get();
                //String title = "title";
                //String posterPath = "poster Path";
                String rating = "rating";
                String releaseDate = "release Date";
                String overview = "overview";

                final int numberOfItemsInResp = object.length();
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInResp; i++)
                {
                    try{
                        title = object.get("title").toString();
                        movieID = (object.getInt("id"));
                        posterPath = object.get("poster_path").toString();
                        rating = object.get("vote_average").toString();
                        releaseDate = object.get("release_date").toString();
                        overview = object.get("overview").toString();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                String urlStr = BASE_URL + FILE_SIZE + posterPath;
                tvTitle.setText(title);
                tvRating.setText("Rating: " + rating + "/10");
                tvReleaseDate.setText("Released: " + releaseDate);
                tvOverview.setText("Plot \n" + overview);

                new SetPosterTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVPoster))
                        .execute(urlStr);
                imgVPoster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ibtnOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("MovieDetails", urlStr);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You called get() after execute, which defeats the purpose of the Asynctask.

Comment: In another activity I used the same structure to get the objects. Updated with btnSearch. Can you elaborate why it works in this instance, or the proper way to do Asynctasks?

Answer (score 0):

You called .get() on the AsyncTask immediately. It will be null because it has no response yet on the FutureTask. You then checked the length of that null.

```
JSONObject object  = task.execute(searchString, search).get();
...
final int numberOfItemsInResp = object.length();
```

You need to get the result of the task after the task in another thread. The AsyncTask gives helper bit for that which will return the result in the UI thread after it's finished.